# -[NSTaggedPointerString synchronize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, chat, protocols, nsuserdefaults, xmppframework

I have select message and forward to the friend then I have a problem with

```
 id<SOMessage> message = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Message"];
        if (message.type == SOMessageTypeText) {
        NSLog(@"============= text");
    }
    else if (message.type == SOMessageTypePhoto){
        NSLog(@"============= photo");
    }
```

console:

```
-[NSTaggedPointerString type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0000007e65746e7
2016-11-03 15:09:28.596 mY-APP[748:18921] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
[NSTaggedPointerString type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0000007e65746e7'
```

Suppose i was commented if loop it's working. but i need to find out the message.which is text or imag.
what did i wrong here ? please help me

Comment: Post full console data

Comment: The error indicates you have a memory management problem and you dispatch a message to a not existing object. zombies enabled might be of help. Now after the additional information... it is obvious that the call to suer defaults doesn't get you a message object, but something else.

Comment: @Volker FYI, I was set zombies enabled in my xcode and run. Then I having Same problem. No difference. problem at   if(message.type == somessagetext)

Comment: your message is not what it seems to be, have you checked the type returned by your NSUserDefaults call?

Comment: @Volker tq..it's over.